# What is the difference between a.css-class and .css-class selector -- if all my cool-elements are a?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am confused about a simple behaviour of CSS.

I have some `<a class="cool-element"></a>` elements in the DOM, and no other types of elements in the dom have the `"cool-element" class, not even the divs. So I did this to try to select them:

```
.cool-element {
  background-color: red;
}
```

that to my surprise did not work. But if I do

```
a.cool-element {
  background-color: red;
}
```

I get the expected result. I test this in Firefox and in an app that has a lot of other CSS rules loaded. I haven’t tested this in isolation, but I am pretty sure in some other places I am using the first selector with success. Isn't the first selector here supposed to work perfectly fine all the times, or am I missing something?

Comment: With me, the issue usually happens because there is another selector that is more specific which has a different rule, or another selector using the `!important` modifier. Using Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools, you can easily find all selectors that resolve to your element and see which ones are getting applied by the browser and why.

Comment: I can see my css file is loading on the browser, but when I inspect the element and look at its CSS I dont see the rule I specified there at all.

Comment: Do you not see the selector at all? Or you see it and it's struck through? You can inspect the element in chrome under the `Elements` tab. In the right side panel, under `Styles` you should see all styles applicable and the specific rules that got applied. For instance, if you inspect the body element of this page, you should see 4 css rules that match body. And the third and 4th selectors will have a few rules struck through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CSS specificity**

In CSS more specific rules take precedence over less specific rules. You can calculate the specificity of a given selector using the following

1. +1000 for inline styles - Inline styles always take precedence
2. +100 for an id - the id attribute of an element
3. +10 for class or pseudo-class - the class attribute or :hover
4. +1 for an element or pseudo element - html, body, div, p... or :first, :last

A selector overrides all selectors with less point than it. If they have the same number of points then order matters.

Examples

```
a.class-name = 1 + 10 = 11
a#id.class-name = 1 + 100 + 10 = 111
a.class-name.class2-name = 1 + 10 + 10 = 21
```

Until I learned how the points are calculated CSS was a dark art in my mind. There is a good article on [css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) which might do a better job of explaining it - jump to the Calculating CSS Specificity Value section

**Order matters**

As Jorge Alvarado mentioned order matters, so if you have two rules that apply to the same elements, the second style will override the first one.

```
a.class-name { background: red } #this rule will be overridden
a.class-name { background: green } #this rule will be applied
```

Answer (score 1):

I think sometimes the problems are not the selectors of your classes in css, but the order you put them on, so if you had that class first, and then another rule that overrides or changes them, you will never see the expected result. try to organize the way your rules are being applied and compare again.

Let's suppose this:

```
<div class="topclass">
   <a class="myclass1" href="#">a link</a>
</div>

a.myclass1{
    background-color:red;
}

a{
  background-color:blue;
 }

.topclass a{
   background-color:yellow;
 }
```

the final rendered color is yellow for your anchor.

Comment: can you give a small example? Also is using the second selector preferred or first one in this scenario?

Comment: thank you for the example. In my case the problem was with CSSspecifity which I did not know about until Enrico mentioned above. By adding `a` I was increasing the specificity of my rule and that it why it would work.